# Jquery how to get attr tag value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the value in 'c_name' for the row I clicked on. Why is this not working? What's the correct syntax argggg

http://jsfiddle.net/UW38e/400/

### Heading

```
<table id="choose-address-table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
            <th>Name/Nr.</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>Town</th>
            <th>Postcode</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td c_name="nr"><span>50</span>
            </td>
            <td>Some Street 1</td>
            <td>Glasgow</td>
            <td>G0 0XX</td>
            <td>United Kingdom</td>
         <button type="button" class="use-address">get value </button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

### From table syntax

```
$("#choose-address-table").click(function() {
    var $row = $(this).attr("c_name"); // Find the text
      var $row = $(this).find(["c_name"]);
    // Let's test it out
    alert($row);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#choose-address-table` does not have an attribute named `c_name`.
It however has a cell with that attribute.

From you fiddle you can use the attribute selector to select the cell you need to get the value

```
$(".use-address").click(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
    var $text = $row.find("[c_name]").text(); // Find the text

    // Let's test it out
    alert($text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UW38e/406/

---

From the table point of view

```
$("#choose-address-table").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".use-address")){// button clicked
        var $row = $(e.target).closest("tr");    // Find the row
        var $text = $row.find("[c_name]").text(); // Find the text

        // Let's test it out
        alert($text);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UW38e/407/

Comment: Yes, but I wanted it from the scope of the table as well thanks for this though

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting, I believe, to find the row, and then find the `td` that has a `c_name` attribute, and then get the text inside that `td` or inside the `span` inside that `td`.  Use:

```
var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
var c_nameText = $($row).find('td[c_name]').text(); // Find the text
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/UW38e/403/) here.